# Update rows on to tables in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to update the rows of two tables (song & words).

How can I do it using the same query?
Here's my first update:

```
string query2 = "Update myproject.song set house_number = '" + first.Length + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL permits you to multiple tables as shown here:
[MySQL update syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE song,artist SET song.title=a,artist.song_count=b
WHERE artist.id=song.artist_id;
```

In this example, song, and artist are the two tables with rows, title and song_count respectively.  The WHERE clause ensures that this is being done based on your criteria

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't update two tables at the same time.  Try updating song, then using the primary key of song to update the correct row in words.

Comment: Updating word by using the primary key of song should be done on mysql itself or via c# ?

Comment: This is simply untrue.  You can update multiple tables in a single query as shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: The link you provided shows how to reference multiple tables in an update statement.  Look at all the examples, and you'll see only one table is being updated.  For instance, two tables are referenced here, but only one has a spot in the SET clause, so only one is actually being updated.  UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;